# Migrating to identity with [Id] replacement

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have an existing database with my users. But the [Id] column is just a number

```
[Id]                     BIGINT         IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT [Users] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
```

I want to transfer all of my users to a new AspNetUsers table where

```
[Id]                   NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
```

I saw all the explanations on migrating, but I couldnt find how can I generate a new Id in SQL Insert statment. All examples show only how to transfer data from the old database to a new one.
Can someone please give me an example of SQL code that copies all the data from one table and inserts it to another table with new generated unique value.

Comment: MS Sql i suppose. Use newid() `select cast(newid() as varchar(36)) , ..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final script that worked:

```
INSERT INTO AspNetUsers
(
    Id,
    Email,
    UserName,
    .
    .
    .
    )
SELECT
    CAST(NEWID() AS NVARCHAR (128)),
    Email,
    UserName,
    .
    .
    .
FROM Users
```